# c# call object by unique property

Tags: c#, object, methods, unique, call

I have a class Referrals. When you create an object in the class, it checks that the input strings are unique (and therefore never allows duplicate objects). But when I find that input string str1 is equal to that of a previously created object, instead of creating a new object or just returning false, i want to change a property of the already created object. But i can't figure out how to do this, as the method has no way of knowing the name of the object. But I know something unique about it! I feel like this must be enough to *somehow* call it, and do what I need to do.

Any ideas?
**THANKS!**

Here is the class:

```
public class Referral
{
    public class Referral
    {
        public string URL;
        public Dictionary<string, int> Keywords = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        private static Dictionary<string, string> URLs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        private int HowManyURLs;
        private bool UniqueURL;
        private bool UniqueKeyword;

        public Referral(string MyURL, string MyKeyword, int MyOccurrences)   //Constructor
        {
    if (HowManyURLs == 0)
    {
        URL = MyURL;
        Keywords.Add(MyKeyword, MyOccurrences);
        URLs.Add(MyURL, MyKeyword);
        HowManyURLs++;
    }

    else
    {
        // RESET FLAGS
        UniqueURL = true;
        UniqueKeyword = true;

        for ( int i = 0; i < HowManyURLs; i++ )
        {
        if ( URLs.ContainsKey( MyURL ) )
        {
            // TRIP URL FLAG
            UniqueURL = false;

            // NOW CHECK KEYWORDS OF URL << THIS IS WHAT I CAN'T DO!
            if ( URLs.ContainsKey( MyKeyword ) )
            {
            // TRIP KEYWORD FLAG
            UniqueKeyword = false;

             // ADD TO OCCURRENCES
    //      Referral[MyURL].Occurrences += MyOccurrences;
            }
        }
        }

    // IF BOTH FLAGS TRUE
    if  ( UniqueURL == true && UniqueKeyword == true )
    {
        URL = MyURL;
        Keywords.Add(MyKeyword, MyOccurrences);
        URLs.Add(MyURL, MyKeyword);
        HowManyURLs++;
    }

    }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to do when it comes to both your question and your code.

For one thing this isn't a method it is a constructor so returning false is not an option and not creating a new Referral is not an option.

Also your for loop appears do perform the same checks each time through the loop with no changes.  Should your second if be:
if ( Keywords.ContainsKey( MyKeyword ) )

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a List of Referral objects *outside* of the Referral object itself? That way you can check the List to see if the object with your criteria already exists. If so, update that object. If not, create a new one and add it to the list.

Either that or use a static list, also declared outside of the Referrals class.

I'm not 100% sure where you're going with this, so hopefully one of those approaches will work for you.

Comment: Why outside the Referral class? If the only place it's used is in the Referral constructor, there's no reason to expose it outside the class.

Comment: it sounds to me like they're trying to maintain a collection of objects, and want to add new objects when one does not exist and update an existing one when one does exist. A collection of those objects seems like the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Dictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) method?

I didn't quite understand what you're attempting to do with your code, and it's a bit late.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a controller class that will maintain a collection of referral objects in order to achieve the prerequisite checking and updating of the object.

Something like:

```
public class Referrals
{
    private List<Referral> refs;

    public class Referrals()
    {
        this.refs = new List<Referral>();
    }

    public Referral Add(string MyURL, string MyKeyword)
    {
       var ref = this.refs.Find(delegate(Referral r) { return r.URL == MyURL; });
       if (ref != null)
       {
           if (ref.Keyword == MyKeyword)
           {
               ref.IncrementOccurrences();
           }
       }
       else
       {
           ref = new Referral(MyURL, MyKeyword);
           this.refs.Add(ref);
       }
       return ref;
    }
}
```

And I would change your Referral class to not take in Occurrences as a variable. This should be handled privately to the object:

```
public class Referral
{
   private string url;
   private string keyword;
   private int occurrences;

   public Referral(string MyURL, string MyKeyword)
   {
      this.url = MyURL;
      this.keyword = MyKeyword;
      this.occurrences = 1;
   }

   public int Occurrences { get { return this.occurrences; } }
   public string URL { get { return this.url; } }
   public string Keyword { get { return this.keyword; } }

   public void IncrementOccurrencies()
   {
      this.occurrences++;
   } 

}
```